# Mathematica not round small value to zero

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I have a simple question, for the specific project I am working on I would like mathematica to not evaluate extremely small decimals (of the order of ~10^-90) to zero. I would like a scientific notation return. When I evaluate similar expressions into WolframAlpha I receive a non-zero result.
For an example of a specific evaluation which returns non-zero in wolfram, and zero in mathematica:

Mathematica:

```
In[219]:= Integrate[dNitrogen, {v, 11000, Infinity}]

Out[219]= 0.
```

Compared to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%203.92872*10%5E-10%20E%5E%28-1.683*10%5E-6%20v%5E2%29%20v%5E2%20from%2011000%20to%20infinity):

I've tried searching around myself but oddly enough have only found solutions to the opposite of my problem -Those wanting when mathematica evaluates the small number to print as zero, this seems to involve some use of the Chop function.

Thanks for help/suggestions.

Comment: Since we have no idea what your dNitrogen expression is we are limited in pinpointing the problem. Since you are getting a decimal point on output then you have buried somewhere inside your dNitrogen one or more numbers with a decimal point and you have only given it a few digits of precision. Mathematica tracks the precision of every part of a calculation and if you say dNitrogen=0.5 Mathematica assumes you only have 1 digit of precision. Increase precision of all constants constants with decimal points so that every one has 100+ digits of precision and see how this changes. Show the results

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) instead of [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html). By default it will give you the precision you're wanting, and it's also configurable through the [`PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal.html) parameter (and other parameters, see the NIntegrate docs for details).